# CascadeType.PERSIST with @OneToMany and Map<Entity, Entity>

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Invoking EntityManager.persist() on an instance of A is cascaded to the value of the Map as expected, in this case one or many instances of B. But its also cascaded to the key of the map, which i would like to avoid. Is there a way to cascade em.persist(A) explicitly to Entity B and not to Entity C?

```
    class A {
      ...
      @Id
      @Column(name = "A_ID")
      private Long id;

      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST
      @MapKey(name = "c")
      private Map<C, B> vertices = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    }

    class B {
      ...

      @Id
      @ManyToOne(targetEntity = NetzEntity.class)
      @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", referencedColumnName = "A_ID")
      private A a;

      @Id
      @ManyToOne(targetEntity = NetzEntity.class)
      @JoinColumn(name = "C_ID", referencedColumnName = "C_ID")
      private C c;
    }

    class C {
      ...
      @Id
      @Column(name = "C_ID")
      private Long id;
    }
```